# optimize common parameters across several equations using least squares in python

Tags: python, least-squares

I would like to optimize common parameters among several equations, but i dont know how to fit them simultaneously.

The problem is essentially like this, with four equations to solve and three parameters to optimize:

a+b+c+1750=T

12=a/T*100

15=b/T*100

37=c/T*100

where I would like to find the optimal values of a,b, and c. Does anybody have a suggestion, perhaps using a least squares method? I am only familiar when there is but one equation to solve.

Comment: So you actually have 4 parameters, a, b, c, and T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your equations actually have 4 parameters, a, b, c and T, so you have a set of 4 linear equations with 4 parameters:

```
a + b + c - T = -1750
100 * a - 12 * Y = 0
100 * b - 15 * Y = 0
100 * c - 37 * Y = 0
```

You can solve this using the coefficients in a matrix:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1., 1., 1., -1.],
              [100., 0, 0, -12.],
              [0, 100., 0, -15.],
              [0, 0, 100., -37.]])
b = np.array([-1750., 0, 0, 0])
```

If there is an analytical solution, you can use

```
res = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
# res: [  583.33333333   729.16666667  1798.61111111  4861.11111111]
```

Otherwise (or for a more general case) you can approximate a solution using least-squared algorithm

```
res, err, _, __ = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)
# res: [  583.33333333   729.16666667  1798.61111111  4861.11111111]
```

Comment: I like the idea of solving with linear algebra. Do you happen to know if this protocol allows for solving for integer-only solutions of the variables?

Comment: @EVS I don't think it can, `numpy.linalg.lstsq` seems to convert the input data to something like float.

Answer (score 1):

This is a system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns. It can be solved algebraically.

solving for a, b, and c and plugging into the first equation. I'm assuming the (*100) is in the denominator of the equations for a, b, and c.

```
12 x 100 x T + 15 x 100 x T + 37 x 100 x T + 1750 = T
T = 3.66
```

Then, plug this value of T into the equations for a, b, and c